# Visual Studio 2010-intellisense and highlighting in javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, javascript-intellisense

In one of my solutions in javascripts files the intellisense suddenly stopped working.
All of the features are disabled - ctrl+space doesn't bring the list - like this 
I took the print screen from another solution[image]

and also the file looks like it was plain text -keywords has no colors. 
[image]

I tried to open new solution and move the files there - still the same.
Files has intellisense only when I am debugging.
It feels like VS2010 see that those files are text files instead of js files.
It has something to do with tfs because it first happened to another member of the team and as soon as I took latest version of the solution - it happened to me.
When I create new js file - it looks fine , BUT after saving 
the file , closing and reopen - again it is not colored
I found out that the problem is in one specific project - if I add js files to another project in the same solution it seems to be ok.

Comment: Could you tell me what extension the file is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and tests. This problem could be a couple of things:

1. Your file's extension is not .JS.
2. You are using an express edition.
3. You have not installed the Web Developer component on your installation (or removed it).

Let me know if this help you, If not I will look forward something else.

The complete reference about the JScript Intellisense on msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb385682(v=vs.100).aspx

As you can see in the image below, I just created a single javascript file in my Visual Studio 2010 *with Web developers components* and it is working:

[image]

Comment: I don't think neither is the answer - in other solutions everything works just fine- same machine !!! Moreover - when I open the files in another solution - whey are colored .

Comment: Have you tried to reset your configuration settings? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: If you go to  Tools | Options | Text Editor | JavaScript | General, the Statement Completion options are turned on?

Comment: I just editted the answer with a link to the complete reference of the JScript Intellisense on Visual Studio 2010. I cannot figure out what is happening.

Comment: yes , everything looks just like in other solutions , except in this one it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this problem ....
I wanted to watch some value with QuickWatch (Shift+F9)
I got the message "Unable to evaluate the expression. The object invoked has disconnected from its clients." I pressed the green icon to refresh the values. After I closed the QuickWatch window I realized that I got the intellisense and highlighting back. 
After a checkin to TFS, my colleague pulled the solution and got the intellisense and highlighting back as well.
Probably some weird bug in VS2010.